# How to display dynamically images from a folder in php?

Tags: php, image, dynamic, display

I have a page that diplays each project from my portfolio with detail. Each project have multiple images but not the same number of images. I have all the images saved in a folder in my server.

The images' names are something like "11.webp" where the fisrt "1" is the project_id (from database table) and the second "1" is the number that displays the amount of images for each project. so one project can have images 11.webp, 12.webp etc.

I want to display the images dynamically for each project in a grid that I customized. But I also want the grid to change if the amount of images per project are even or odd. (to be more specific, when the images for a project are even I want the layout that I currently have in this page https://agapikarageorgou.gr/projectpage.php, and the they are odd I want in the last row to have one full image instead of the 2 smaller ones)

https://agapikarageorgou.gr/projectpage.php this is the page for reference

I have seen that maybe the glob() function can help me, but i think i should add a for loop inside just to return all the images for a specific project id.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First of all, you should probably change that image naming scheme - because as soon as you got more than 9 projects, or would ever want to add more than 9 images to a certain project, you'd be in trouble here. At least insert some sort of separator character between project id and the image number.

Comment: Even better, use folders. Put “project 1’s” stuff in the “project 1” folder. Or better, if you want some (potential) SEO juice, give the folder a name and store that name in the database, and maybe give each file a more descriptive name, optionally starting with a numeric index for sorting

Comment: okay, thanks! I think im gonna change the name to 1001.web 1002.web etc. Any tips on the rest of the question?